# Looking for better solution than this IF, ELSEIF, ELSE approach

Tags: jquery

This code works but I'm certain there's a more efficient way to do the job with a function that folks here above my novice level might help with.

I am changing button label text strings based on the count of divs by type. If the count is zero, the button is hidden. If the count equals one, the term is singular. If the count is greater than one, the term is plural.

```
var countAll = $('li.posts').size();
var countText = $('div.text').size();
var countPhoto = $('div.photo').size();
var countQuote = $('div.quote').size();
var countLink = $('div.link').size();
var countChat = $('div.chat').size();
var countAudio = $('div.audio').size();
var countVideo = $('div.video').size();
var countAnswer = $('div.answer').size();
var countConversation = $('div.conversation').size();


$('.showAll').html("show all " + countAll + " posts ");

if (countText == 1) {
       $('.showText').html(countText + " text");
   } else if (countText > 1) {
        $('.showText').html(countText + " texts");
      } else {
        $('.showText').hide();
   };

if (countPhoto == 1) {
       $('.showPhoto').html(countPhoto + " photo");
   } else if (countPhoto > 1) {
        $('.showPhoto').html(countPhoto + " photos");
      } else {
        $('.showPhoto').hide();
   };

if (countQuote == 1) {
       $('.showQuote').html(countQuote + " quote");
   } else if (countQuote > 1) {
        $('.showQuote').html(countQuote + " quotes");
      } else {
        $('.showQuote').hide();
   };

if (countLink == 1) {
       $('.showLink').html(countLink + " link");
   } else if (countLink > 1) {
        $('.showLink').html(countLink + " links");
      } else {
        $('.showLink').hide();
   };   

if (countChat == 1) {
       $('.showChat').html(countChat + " chat");
   } else if (countChat > 1) {
        $('.showChat').html(countChat + " chats");
      } else {
        $('.showChat').hide();
   };

if (countAudio == 1) {
       $('.showAudio').html(countAudio + " audio");
   } else if (countAudio > 1) {
        $('.showAudio').html(countAudio + " audios");
      } else {
        $('.showAudio').hide();
   };

if (countVideo == 1) {
       $('.showVideo').html(countVideo + " video");
   } else if (countVideo > 1) {
        $('.showVideo').html(countVideo + " videos");
      } else {
        $('.showVideo').hide();
   };

if (countAnswer == 1) {
       $('.showAnswer').html(countAnswer + " answer");
   } else if (countAnswer > 1) {
        $('.showAnswer').html(countAnswer + " answers");
      } else {
        $('.showAnswer').hide();
   };

if (countConversation == 1) {
       $('.showConversation').html(countConversation + " conversation");
   } else if (countConversation > 1) {
        $('.showConversation').html(countConversation + " conversations");
      } else {
        $('.showConversation').hide();
   };
```

Thanks in advance for your help! Still learning.

Comment: It should belong to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Maybe ask this over on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Sorry, was not aware of that area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two key ways to improve this code:

1. Using a function or `for` loop to remove repetitive code.
2. Using ternary to remove the `else if`

## Function/For Loop

You repeat the code structure several times. The best way to do this is to write the code once, and make it act several times. I will utilise both a function and a for loop.
Your basic structure is always the same - take a div tag, get the size, then edit a class tag `.show<name>`.

## Ternary

A ternary construct works on the basis of `if-else-return` and fits in 1 line. It will give you one of two values based on a boolean test. For example:

```
if (number>1) return "votes" else return "vote"`
```

The syntax for this is `((test) ? "value-if-true" : "value-if-false")`.

## Your final product:

```
$('.showAll').html("show all " + $('li.posts').size() + " posts ");

var counts = ["text", "photo", "quote", "link", "chat", "audio", "video", "answer", "conversation"];

function showcount(name) {
    var divcount = $("div."+name).size()
    var classname = ".show" + name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1);
    if (divcount >= 1) {
        $(classname).html(divcount + " " + name + ((divcount==1) ? "" : "s"));
    }
    else {
        $(classname).hide();
    }
}

for (var i=0; i<counts.length; i++) {
    showcount(counts[i]);
}
```

I haven't tested this; please let me know if it works or otherwise.

Comment: I get a syntax error here: $(".show" + name).html(countText + " " + name + ((divcount==1) ? "" : "s");

Comment: Ahh, needs  ((divcount==1) ? "" : "s")); ?

Comment: No joy. Buttons show without text (except for first "showAll")

Comment: <s>Are you getting any errors, or is it just the buttons have no text? And if the count is <=0, is it hiding them correctly?</s> I may have found the issue, I had a `countText` variable instead of `divcount`. Does it work for you now? (Also fixed missing parenthesis).

Comment: Thanks for the extra effort. I recall no errors. The appropriate buttons appeared and they linked correctly, just no text. Will test the new code.

Comment: Did more testing. This appears to fix issue: $(".show" + name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1)).html(divcount + " " + name + ((divcount==1) ? "" : "s"));  Will continue to test. Wondering now if original divcount approach would've worked?

Comment: Oh yes, now I see the issue. The hiding code had .showText whereas the HTML-changing code had .showtext (note the lowercase T). Fixing now.

Answer (score 4):

In this case, you can use a common method which will receive the selector and the text:

```
var countAll = $('li.posts').size();
$('.showAll').html("show all " + countAll + " posts "); 
//Call the provided method foreach of your divs and links, one call for each, 
// instead of the relevant .size() and IF..ELSE blocks
SetVisibilityAndText('div.text', '.showText','text');
SetVisibilityAndText('div.photo', '.showPhoto', 'photo');
//etc for your other selectors / divs

function SetVisiblityAndText(countSelector, linkSelector, text){
 var count = $(countSelector).size();
  if (count == 1) {        
     $(linkSelector).html(count + " " +text);    
  } 
  else if (count > 1) {         
     $(linkSelector).html(count + " "+ text+ "s");       
  }  
  else 
  {         
      $(linkSelector).hide();    
  }; 
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it. Nice answer. +1

Comment: lol, i was sure there'd be 10 such answers by the type i finish typing :)

Comment: Thanks. This one got the most votes and looks very efficient. But, I have no idea how to implement. Which bits of the original code should be removed? How exactly would I replace it with yours? Sorry, novice here.

Comment: i edited and provided sample 2 calls for text and photos, note that Scott S answers bellow mine does the same in a pretty convinient way as well. At the bottom line, instead of each IF..ELSE block, and the relevant `var countX = $('div.x').size()`, you need to call my method (with x being text,photos,etc).

Comment: No joy. All buttons show without text including types with zero count (except for first "showAll"). Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

html:

```
<label class='show' id='photo'>
<div class='photo'></div>.. etc
```

js:

```
$('label.show').each(function(){
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
   var count = $('div.'+id).count();
   var mul = (count > 1) ? 's' : '';
   $(this).html(count+' '+id+mul);
});
```

I'm sure this could look better...

Comment: nice concept, its usually a good idea to arrange ur html by using attributes/classes and then working on it with jquery in a single block/method +1

Answer (score 0):

You can centralize all your logic in a single function:

```
function check( count, el ){
var $el = $(el);
if (count == 1) {
       $( el ).html(count + " text");
    } else if (count > 1) {
        $el.html(count + " texts");
    } else {
        $el.hide();
    } 
}
```

And then use that:

```
check( countText, '.showText' );
check( countPhoto, '.showPhoto' );
//....
```